# Usage of .map with defaultdict

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, defaultdict, map-function

I have a pandas dataframe and I have to fill a new column based on the values of an existing column, associating the values of a dictionary.

```
mydict={'key1':'val1', 'key2':'val2'}
df['new_col']=df['keys'].map(mydict)
```

Now I have a similar problem, but the dictionary is now a `defaultdict(list)`

```
my_defdict=defaultdict(list)
my_defdict={'key1':['val1','item1'], 'key2':['val2','item2']}
```

and I need a new column with the second element of the list, something like

```
df['new_col2']=df['keys'].map(my_defdict()[1])
```

which is of course wrong. How can I perform this operation without creating another normal dictionary?

Comment: Why does it matter that you have a defaultdict now? Wouldn't the solution be the same regardless...? And will all values have at least two elements per list?

Comment: Reply to my comment? Or at least respond to the answer?

Comment: My apologies, I really thought I answered. Your solution worked as a charm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming all your values have at least two items per list, add an `str[1]` at the end:

```
df['new_col2'] = df['keys'].map(my_defdict).str[1]
```

Or,

```
df['new_col2'] = df['keys'].map(my_defdict).str.get(1)
```